# Graphite: merge series containing multiple values

Tags: grafana, graphite

Is there a way to merge two "dictionaries" of values in Graphite? That is to say, I want to start with a series:

```
AnimalsByCountry
    England
        Cats
        Dogs
    France
        Cats
        Dogs 
        Birds
```

And combine them into  series:

```
AnimalsInWorld
    Cats  // = AnimalsByCountry.England.Cats + AnimalsByCountry.France.Cats
    Dogs  // = AnimalsByCountry.England.Dogs + AnimalsByCountry.France.Dogs
    Birds // = AnimalsByCountry.France.Birds
```

Sorry if this is an obvious question; I'm new to Graphite and this seems like a simple operation but I can't find any functions to do it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNodes

`groupByNodes(animalsbycountry.*.*,'sum',2)`